# MVC 5 add dynamic fields to form using jquery and save it to model

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to have a form in MVC 5 where you can add dynamic fields using jQuery as here:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yyNLf/)

And then post those fields to model using MVC?

In fact my viewmodel where I want to save those values is a `List<string>` where all those values will be saved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When dynamically adding the inputs you need to ensure they are named/indexed correctly for postback.  For example, if your post action method is

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(List<string> text)
{
  ...
```

then your inputs need to be named

```
<input name="[0].text" value=.../>
<input name="[1].text" value=.../>
<input name="[2].text" value=.../>
```

so you need to modify the script to create the correct name attribute. Note the indexes need to start at zero and be sequential so you will need to take into account what happens if an input in the middle of the list is removed by the user.

Comment: Is this using @Html.BeginCollectionItem ?

Comment: No you don't necessarily that - its just a helper that you may find easier to work with. The key to posting back a collection is to name the elements correctly with an indexer

Comment: What about if I will have a `List<object>` where `object` has 2 properties: `Id` and `value`. How the elements should be named?

Comment: For example `List<Employee>` and `Employee` has properties  `FirstName` and `LastName`, then the inputs would be `<input name="employees[0].FirstName" ...` and `<input name="employees[0].LastName" ...` and postback to `public ActionResult Edit(List<Employee> employees)`